# How to get all the object properties of an ontology using sparql?

Tags: sparql, ontology

I want to query an ontology and get all its object properties, I have tried this query but it doesn't work

```
select ?p
where { ?s ?p ?o.
        ?s rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.
       }
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: why not just doing `select ?p where {?p rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty}`? And what means "does not work"? That is very unspecific ...

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for your answer, I tried the query that you have suggested and it works.